# Google Analytics API - get Access Token without authenticate with the "consent screen"

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, access-token

I'm developing a website that uses Google Analytics API. I followed this tutorial -> https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api?hl=pt-PT

and everything works fine. I get the "consent screen", I give "permissions" and I'm redirected to my website, with all information.

But, I want to change the things a little. I want to get all info of Google Analytics, without using the "consent screen", i.e. , using just the Google Analytics code (UA-XXXXXXXX-X) or any other way.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: This is how the Oauth2 protocol works.
However, you can create a private key and by loading it you might be able to skip that auth step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the Google analytics API you need authorization (permission to access the data). Becouse you only want to see your own data I recommend that you look into a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  By setting up a service account in Google apis console it will allow you to access your own data with out needing to login and autenticate the code all the time.

---

Here is an example of how to use a service account in php [ServiceAccount](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/prediction/serviceAccount.php)

That sample project is for the PredictionService not the google analytics service.  You need to edit it slightly.

```
require_once '../../src/Google/Client.php'; 
require_once '../../src/Google/Service/Analytics.php'; 

// Set your client id, service account name, and the path to your private key. 
// For more information about obtaining these keys, visit: 
// https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts

const CLIENT_ID = 'INSERT_YOUR_CLIENT_ID'; 
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'INSERT_YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME'; 


// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't 
// readable by others.

const KEY_FILE = '/super/secret/path/to/key.p12'; 


$client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->setApplicationName("Google Analytics Sample"); 


// Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the 
// Google API Console when the service account was created. 


$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials( 
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME(Email), 
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'), 
    file_get_contents(KEY_FILE)) 
); 


$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID); 
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

Now you have `$service` that you can use with the rest of your calls.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I will check this possibility and then give feed back. :)